# How to delete an element by index from a numpy array in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to delete an element from a numpy array by index.

The commands

```py
arr = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
del arr[0]
```

The code above throws an error saying `cannot delete array elements`.
Using `pop` doesn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate because this one asks about deleting just one element rather than many. But maybe others can look into it and decide.

Comment: del and pop are python list operations, and don't apply to `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) for it.

```
arr = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
arr = np.delete(arr, 0)
```